# Count distinct over multiple columns in data.table

Tags: r, count, data.table

I observe `user`s at different `time`s and in different `situation`s and potentially I see them multiple times, like so:

```
df <- data.table(time = c(1,1,1,2,2),
                 user = c(1,1,2,1,2),
                 situation = c(1,1,1,2,2),
                 observation = c(1,2,1,1,1))
```

What I would like to do is to count the number of `user`-`situation`s in each time period using `data.table`. Expected output:

```
result <- data.table(time = c(1,2),
                     user_situations = c(2,2))
```

I know I can do this in a chained way:

```
 unique(df[, .(time, user, situation)])[, .(user_situations = .N), .(time)]
```

but wonder if there's a simple way to do this in one go.

Comment: You might try `df[, .(user_situations = uniqueN(.SD[,.(user, situation)])), time]` but I think your method is more efficient.

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me, I would slightly modify to `unique(df, by = c("user","situation"))[, .N, by = time]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Wanna post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

`dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.table(time = c(1,1,1,2,2),
             user = c(1,1,2,1,2),
             situation = c(1,1,1,2,2),
             observation = c(1,2,1,1,1))

df %>% group_by(time) %>%
  distinct(user, situation) %>%
  summarise(user_situations = n())

# tbl_dt [2 × 2]
   time user_situation
  <dbl>          <int>
1     1              2
2     2              2
```

Comment: Yup, in `dplyr` this stuff is pretty easy. Unfortunately I need one for `data.table`

Comment: How is this any easier than the `data.table` solution? This is just plain verbatism

Comment: I'd like to add that this ```summarise(n_distinct(c(user, situation)))``` - which I thought would work - DOESN'T give the correct result. thanks your solution worked!